# how to use websocket inbound connections in mulesoft?

Tags: mule, dataweave, mulesoft, anypoint-studio, anypoint-platform

I have use case where I need to create websocket connector as listener and that should listen the request and accepts request and sends to other websocket (which furhther will take again access token and process further but am unable to listen the listener websocket).
Please help me with the configuration.
am using new inbound connection

Comment: Can you please share what you've configured? What is the problem you're having? Are you seeing an exception? Are you receiving any data?

Comment: I have only configured On new inbound connection connector and trying to print the response.
But the inbound connector is not listening I don't know how to make it configure

Comment: sharing the details means sharing the 'code', ie the XML of the relevant configurations/flows of the Mule application.

Comment: Have you read the documentation and tried to follow the instructions?

Comment: yes, I tried everything possible..I could have shared you the code here but there are client details so am unable to send.

Comment: It is hard to help without details/reproduction.

Comment: Did you get an example working first like this one? https://docs.mulesoft.com/websockets-connector/1.0/websockets-connector-examples . Then you can adapt it to your use case. All the authentication part, like token validation, should happen on the "on-new-inbound-connection-flow"